# java util Date comparison with Criteria api is not working as expected

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I'm trying to filter out some data from database using `between` of CriteriaBuilder. I am using java.util.Date for my inputs and entity columns. I'm always getting results as per input date - 1. For e.g. if my input date is 16-12-2019, then I'm getting data for 15-12-2019 as well. I'm not able to understand this strange behaviour. I'm using below method:

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(root.get(Constants.COL_REGISTRATION_DATE),
                    registrationStartDate, registrationEndDate));
```

I tried below method as well, but still same result.

```
Predicate startDatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Constants.COL_REGISTRATION_DATE), registrationStartDate);
            Predicate endDatePredicate = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Constants.COL_REGISTRATION_DATE), registrationEndDate);

            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(startDatePredicate, endDatePredicate));
```

Did anyone face such issues. Please help me out to figure this out.

Comment: Don't know if it is the problem, but if you are using Java 8, then don't use `java.util.Date` but the modern API `java.time`...

Comment: @deHaar I'm also in favor of using java.time but somehow can't use it because of restrictions

Comment: OK, nevermind... I think you have to provide more code.

Comment: @deHaar I tried with LocalDate, solution is working as expected. I believe it has something to do with format of java.util.Date

Comment: Yes, I think so, too... There's a reason for a new datetime API having been implemented. Maybe even just an issue with `java.util.Date` apart from the format.

Comment: There are three forms of datetime fields in JDBC: `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. Each of them extend `java.util.Date`. You should try to use more specific type `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to :

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(root.get(Constants.COL_REGISTRATION_DATE),
                LocalDate.parse(registrationStartDate), 
                LocalDate.parse(registrationEndDate))
);
```

Comment: oh you have different pattern. Then you need to add your date pattern to LocalDate.parse as 2nd argument if my code doesn't work

Comment: I can't use LocalDate.parse since column is of java.util.Date. One thing is for sure that the issue is with util Date format only as my my solution is working fine with LocalDate but due to some restrictions I can't use it..